# trim to 2 decimals

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field2').value,2)*100))/100 + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field3').value,2)*100))/100;"
```

Most numbers round ok to 2 decimal points which is what I need.

However, with an example like

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('21.29').value,2)*100))/100 + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('54.70').value,2)*100))/100;"
```

Field 1 is returning `75.99000000000001`  How can I trim to `75.99` consistently?

Answer (score 58):

```
var num = 5 / 6;

var display = num.toFixed(2)

num outputs: 0.8333333333333334

display outputs: "0.83"
```

Comment: .toFixed converts the integer to a string though, correct? Is there a JavaScript method to simply trim (not round) an integer to a certain decimal place, while still keeping it an integer?

Comment: @KyleVassella—You could convert it to a number afterwards: `Number(num.toFixed(2))`. Also, it can't become an integer, as integers do not have decimals.

Comment: if your num would be -2.3699 then your code will round off to 2 decimals - the question is for trimming upto 2 decimals

Comment: `0.999.toFixed(2)` does not trim to `0.99`, but rounds up to `1`

Answer (score 9):

Use the method `toFixed(2)` to fix it at 2 decimal places:

```
(Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('21.29').value,2)*100))/100 + 
  Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('54.70').value,2)*100))/100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) == "NaN" ? value : 
  parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)` 
would work better. Your code doubles it

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById('21.29').toFixed(2));
```

The toFixed method should take care of the rounding nicely for you.

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue - where I do not wanted to round the value but trim upto 2 decimals

I got the perfect solution for by writing this function and using where ever needed to trim upto 2 decimals

```
function upto2Decimal(num) {
    if (num > 0)
      return Math.floor(num * 100) / 100;
    else
      return Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100;
  }
```

if you call

```
upto2Decimal(2.3699) or upto2Decimal(-2.3699)
// returns 2.36 or -2.36
```

check this solution using your JS console of the browser

Comment: There is a potential for a floating point precision issue here. For ex: `Math.floor(1234.1 * 100) / 100` will result in `1234.09`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
function myFunction() 
{
      var num = "-54.987656";
    var roundedValue = roundMethod(num,5);   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = roundedValue;
}
function roundMethod(numberVal, roundLimit) // This method will not add any additional 0, if decimal places are less than the round limit
{
    var isDecimal = numberVal.indexOf(".") != -1;    
  if(isDecimal)
  {
      if(numberVal.split(".")[1].length > roundLimit)
      {
        return parseFloat(numberVal).toFixed(roundLimit).toString();    
      }else
      {
          return numberVal;
      }
  }else
  {
      return numberVal;
  } 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the fixed number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: trim does not mean rounded