# Javascript value doesn't display decimals unless it's something other than 0.00

Tags: javascript, floating-point

```
//Value being parsed at this point is "150.00"
var productValue = parseFloat($("#product-cost-value-value").text().replace(',', '.'));    

console.log(productValue);
```

The value being logged is `150`.

However if I add some value to it, like this. The value changes to display the two decimals I want.

```
console.log(productValue + 0.01);
```

The value being logged is `150.01`

How can I force my values to show two decimal places at all time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [trim to 2 decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525335/trim-to-2-decimals)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use:

```
console.log(productValue.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `productValue.toFixed(2)` to show 2 decimal places

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Number.prototype.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) (e.g. `productValue.toFixed(2)`) to convert your number into a string formatted to two decimal places.