# KnockoutJS: Needing to format observable values (decimal)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have not used Knockout in a while and am running into an issue when trying to trim the input value of a form field to two decimal places. I created the below computed observable and am subscribing to it by the observable that I want to update with the trimmed value. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**View Model**

```
function createViewModel() {
  var self = {};

  self.SalesRepId = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
  self.PriceAdvanced = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 200 });

  self.decimalValue = ko.computed(function () {
    var num = self.PriceAdvanced().slice(0, (self.PriceAdvanced().indexOf(".")) + 3);
    return num;
  }).extend({ notify: "always" });

  self.PriceAdvanced.subscribe(self.decimalValue);

  return self;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
          <label class="label-col col-xs-4 control-label labelFormat" for="PriceAdvanced"><span class="warn">* </span>Advanced Criminal History Search</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input class="form-control max225" type="text" id="PriceAdvanced" name="PriceAdvanced" data-bind="textInput: PriceAdvanced" size="23" placeholder="$0.00" />
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Were you calling the `ko.applyBindings` method? If not, you need to call that at the end of your code.
2. I think your idea was to use `decimalValue` to limit the decimal places to 2, and then `PriceAdvanced` would subscribe to the updated value of `decimalValue`, right? But subscribe doesn't work like that. Computed observables listen to the observables inside them, and `.subscribe` functions are listeners to the observable itself. So your code would have been in a never-ending loop.
3. Also I think you only wanted to limit decimal places, not the number of digits itself right? So I changed the code to trim the value only if a decimal point exists.

   ```
   function createViewModel() {
     var self = {};

     self.SalesRepId = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
     self.PriceAdvanced = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 200 });

     self.decimalValue = ko.computed(function () {
         var num = self.PriceAdvanced().indexOf(".") > -1?  self.PriceAdvanced().slice(0, (self.PriceAdvanced().indexOf(".")+3)): self.PriceAdvanced();
         //return num;
         self.PriceAdvanced(num);
     }).extend({ notify: "always" });
     return self;
   }

   ko.applyBindings(new createViewModel());
   ```

Note: Your extenders `min: 1`, `max: 200` will not work as `PriceAdvanced` holds a string rather than a number.

Comment: Thank you Ray. This worked perfectly! However, I still have the issue with the min/max validation. Any idea on how to make that work in this case?

Comment: @DeanFriedland
I'm not sure if min and max are valid extenders, because according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922022/max-value-and-numerical-validation-in-knockoutjs), you need the plugin for it to work. Without that, you might need to write a custom extender like in the documenation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Comment: The custom extender should ideally include the decimal limiter as well.

Comment: Yes, we have the validation plugin/library and it is in there. Just not sure why it is not firing

Comment: You could also try applying numbers to PriceAdvanced instead of a string, and use [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525335/trim-to-2-decimals) to limit the decimal places.

Comment: @DeanFriedland oh I see... You could ask a new question, to see why it is not firing, because you would probably need to rewrite the logic if you want to use that plugin as well.

Comment: How would I apply numbers as opposed to a string for that observable? Sorry if that is a dumb question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168363/discussion-between-ray-and-dean-friedland).